# Прокрутить страницу вслед за выдвижным элементом

Tags: javascript

На страницы есть кнопка при нажатии на которую снизу плавно появляется ещё один блок. Сейчас когда пользователь смотрит с телефона он не видит что этот блок выдвигается, как будто ничего не произошло.
Мне хотелось бы прокручивать страницу вслед за раскрывающимся блоком.
Помогите это реализовать, но только на чистом JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть "кнопка" выглядит так:

```
<div id="button">Кнопка</div>
```

тогда в скрипте запишете:

```
getElementById("button").scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});
```

Подробнее о [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Но проблема в том, что тот блок в конец которого надо прокрутить открывается постепенно. А эта функция срабатывает когда тот блок ещё не открылся и соответственно прокручивает страницу не до конца. Если поставить setInterval, тогда прокручивается рывками. А надо, чтобы плавно прокручивалась вслед за плавно открывающимся блоком.

Comment: Возможно ли отследить окончание открытия и укладывается ли прокручивание после полного открытия в концепцию? Если нет, то, думаю, следует рассчитать положение точно такого же, только невидимого блока и прокрутить к нему